# NameError: name 'myFunction' is not defined: "import test" vs "from test import *"

Tags: python

I've been using JUPYTERLAB on GCP and received an error.

In my "*run.py*" script I use a function named "*myFunction*", which is located in another python script called "*test.py*".

In run.py, if I write `import test`, I get a NameError.

However, if I write `from test import *` or `from test import myFunction`, everything runs smoothly.

The following are my questions:

Why did `import test` not work?

What is the difference between `import test` and `from test import *`? Apparently, import * is bad practice.

Comment: because you import only the name `test`, you don't import any other names, if you `import test`, then you need to use `test.myFunction`, also don't use `*` when importing, it is bad practice

Comment: "Why did import test not work?" Well, why do you think it *should* work? "What is the difference between import test and from test import *?" You can [literally copy and paste that entire question, without quotes, into a search engine, and get tons of useful answers](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=What+is+the+difference+between+import+test+and+from+test+import+*%3F).